# Copying and shifting column in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with a list of dates. These are not ordered in the database, but using a SQL SELECT query.

There are two intervals I want to calculate. The first is not a problem, which is calculating the interval between the dates in the same row.

```
Date 1      Date 2      (Interval 1)
1950-01-01  1960-01-01  (10.00)
1951-07-01  1962-01-01  (10.50)
1952-04-01  1964-07-01  (11.25)
1953-07-01  1968-10-01  (15.25)
1958-01-01  1970-01-01  (12.00)
```

However, I also want to calculate the difference between Date 1 of a row, and Date 2 of the row above it (in the SQL SELECT output). Essentially I want the Date 2 column to be copied and shifted down one row (or something to that effect) so that I can calculate Interval 2.

```
Date 1      Date 2      Interval 1  Date 2_shift  Interval 2
1950-01-01  1960-01-01  10.00       
1951-07-01  1962-01-01  10.50       1960-01-01    8.50 
1952-04-01  1964-07-01  11.25       1962-01-01    9.75
1953-07-01  1968-10-01  15.25       1964-07-01    11.00
1958-01-01  1970-01-01  12.00       1968-10-01    10.75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Mihai mentioned, you would need to use a `row_number` field and do a left join to get the previous date values:

```
SET @row_number:= 0;
SET @row_number1:= 0;

select q1.*
      ,q2.Date2 as PreviousDate
from
(SELECT @row_number:= @row_number + 1 AS row_number
        ,dt.*
FROM datetable dt
) q1
left join (SELECT @row_number1:= @row_number1 + 1 AS row_number
        ,dt.*
FROM datetable dt
) q2 on q1.row_number-1 = q2.row_number
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e048/1/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Suppose I wanted the original input to be from a query, how would I go about adding this? I tried to add it with the second select statement, but I keep getting an SQL syntax error with the Cross Apply.

`SELECT Date1, Date2, b.Max_date
FROM  datetable a
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(Date2) Max_date
                    FROM   datetable b
                    WHERE  a.Date1 >= b.Date1
                    ORDER BY a.Date1) b`

Comment: I forgot this was `MySQL` for a minute, as far as I am aware, MySQL does not support `Cross Apply`.

Comment: Also, can you please elaborate a little more on `original input`?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is add a row number column in your query, then left join it with itself on firstinstance.rownumber = secondinstance.rownumber + 1

Then you can do the calculus you need.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name datatype(length) AFTER column_name
```

eg: ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE **Date 2** **Date 2** datatype(length) AFTER **Interval 1**